# How to debug random logouts from OpenStack Dashboard (Horizon)

Tags: apache, openstack, openstack-horizon

I am using OpenStack Ocata release installed on my own servers. Long time all worked well.

A few days ago OpenStack dashboard starts frequently sign out users. And I can't figure out what is wrong.

Why httpd return 302 redirect to the login page? And how to debug what is wrong?

### Httpd access logs:

```
10.0.0.2 - - [21/Mar/2018:08:29:26 +0000] "POST /dashboard/auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://dashboard.example.com/dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/59.0"
10.0.0.2 - - [21/Mar/2018:08:29:27 +0000] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://dashboard.example.com/dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/59.0"
10.0.0.2 - - [21/Mar/2018:08:29:27 +0000] "GET /dashboard/identity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 53953 "http://dashboard.example.com/dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/59.0"
193.169.81.251 - - [21/Mar/2018:08:29:29 +0000] "GET /dashboard/i18n/js/horizon+openstack_dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2372 "http://dashboard.example.com/dashboard/identity/" "Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/59.0"
10.0.0.2 - - [21/Mar/2018:08:29:33 +0000] "GET /dashboard/project/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://dashboard.example.com/dashboard/identity/" "Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/59.0"
10.0.0.2 - - [21/Mar/2018:08:29:33 +0000] "GET /dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/project/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9041 "http://dashboard.example.com/dashboard/identity/" "Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/59.0"
10.0.0.2 - - [21/Mar/2018:08:29:34 +0000] "GET /dashboard/i18n/js/horizon+openstack_dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2372 "http://dashboard.example.com/dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/project/" "Mozilla/5.0 ... Firefox/59.0"
```

### Httpd error logs:

```
[Wed Mar 21 08:29:26.646941 2018] [:error] [pid 41571] Attempted scope to domain default failed, will attemptto scope to another domain.
[Wed Mar 21 08:29:26.851412 2018] [:error] [pid 41571] Login successful for user "exampeuser", remote address 10.0.0.2.
[Wed Mar 21 08:29:27.161127 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 25877] [client 10.0.0.2:44688] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public, referer: http://dashboard.example.com/dashboard/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to Memcached.
In my case, Memcached was DoSed from externally.
To resolve this I bind Memcached to local management interface instead any (0.0.0.0)